# How to pass a pk from template in url to use in view "Django"?

Tags: python, django, html

I'm getting this error:
"ValueError at /5
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' "

I think that I'm passing a string and trying to use it as an int. How do I pass the int I want correctly?

This is the code I have,
in the html template:

```
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'register' activity.pk %}">
             {% csrf_token %}
            <button 
            type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-primary" 
            id="Register">Register
            </button>
    </form>
```

In urls.py:

```
 url(r'^(?P<pk>)', authentication_views.registerAttende, name='register'),
```

In views.py:

```
def registerAttende(request,pk):
    act = Activity.objects.get(pk=pk) //This is the line that is causing the error
    act.save()
    attend = act.attendee.create(student=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

I'm getting that the value of of the variable pk is: u''
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSw24.png

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the url you are trying to hit?

Comment: What do you mean? Which url?

Comment: When you are getting this error?

Comment: Once I click the form button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong - you haven't provided a pattern to capture. It should be:

```
r'^(?P<pk>\d+)'
```